# jquery; images; reloading

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

cant anybody help with loading img content on ajax?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){
$('.bar2').mosaic({
animation:'slide'//fade or slide
});
});

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {                 
  var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  var href = $('#leftNav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #contentProd';
        $('#contentProd').load(toLoad)
}                                           
});
    $('#leftNav li a').click(function(){                          
 var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #contentProd';
    $('#contentProd').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');

 function loadContent() {
    $('#contentProd').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
 function showNewContent() {
    $('#contentProd').show('normal',hideLoader());
}
 function hideLoader() {
    $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
}
 return false;
 });
});
   $('#leftNav li a').click( function() {
   $('#leftNav li a').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
})
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="body3">
  <div class="main"> 
    <article id="content">
      <div class="wrapperProd"  >

        <section class="col5">
      <div id="contentProd">
        <section class="cols pad_left0">
      <div class="wrapper pad_bot2">
    <h5>16 CUBE</h5>
          <figure>
              <div class="mosaic-block bar2"><a href="onePage.php" class="mosaic-overlay">
                <div class="details">
                  <p style="color:#FFF">SOME TEXT*<br />
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><a href="16.php">
                <img src="../../images/pres.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" />


                </a></div>
              </div>
            </figure>
            <a href="16.php" class="small button green"  style="position:relative; top:22px;">More</a> </div>
        </section>
</div>
</article>
</div>
</div>
```

Can I make an removeClass/ID like the 'active' ? :§

MAny tks in advance for any reply!!

KR

p.s. didn´t find any like this quest, so i´ve made registration today :)
great learning website!!!

/////////// EDIT

tks for your reply,

I´ve made and junction of both,

http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/

inside

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

Hoever when try to view in localhost directly, they appear and work, but when the mosaic images content is replaced by other menu, didn´t come up when move in mosaic images again ;±

understand ?

TY

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You really need to clarify your question though. What isn't working? What would a working example result in?

Comment: Made an Quest edit, tks again maxedison

Comment: Still no idea what you're asking. And don't post answers as additional questions / edits.

Answer (score 0):

I´m very new at jquert, plase i need to understand how can force call the .bar2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                 
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#leftNav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #contentProd';
        $('#contentProd').load(toLoad)
    }                           
});
$('#leftNav li a').click(function(){                          
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #contentProd';
    $('#contentProd').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();    
    function loadContent() {
        $('#contentProd').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#contentProd').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;
});
});
$('#leftNav li a').click( function() {
$('#leftNav li a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
})
jQuery(function($){

$('.bar2').mosaic({ animation: 'slide'//fade or slide
});
});
</script>
```

I´ve made and junction of both,

http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/

inside of an ajax content,

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

basacly, the mosaic only appear in one menu bar, from four at all, but the problem is, if i load directly that menu, the images appear, once navigate ut the image menu, and them return they don´t appear ;!

How is possibel to call the .bar2 when the images are beeing requested?

if i put the '.bar2' in

```
 function loadContent() {
        $('#contentProd', '.bar2').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
```

the images are always requested, but they only should be requested on imageMenu,

is the conditional the solution?

Please want to learn this

BR all